# Regex para otimizar mudança nos códigos usando Notepad++

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

Olá, alguém pode por gentileza me ajudar a criar uma expressão regex para o padrão abaixo.

Eu tenho em meu código php o seguinte padrão: `htmlspecialchars($str)` eu preciso criar um expressão que substitua isso por isso: `htmlspecialchars($str,ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8")`

A expressão deve reconhecer o tamanho de `$str` e ignorar ele. No final das contas, eu espero que textos como o abaixo tenham adicionado ao seu final, a string: `ENT_NOQUOTE,"UTF-8`.

Por exemplo: 
Onde eu tenho:

```
htmlspecialchars($table->content)
```

deverá ficar assim:

```
htmlspecialchars($table->content,ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8")
```

Onde eu tenho:

```
htmlspecialchars($_POST['title'])
```

deverá ficar assim:

```
htmlspecialchars($_POST['title'],ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8")
```

Comment: Eu usaria em localizar: `(htmlspecialchars\(\$.+?(?=\)))` e em Substituir: `\1 ,ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8")`

Comment: @danieltakeshi a ideia é boa, mas se o autor já tiver algum outro que esteja correto isso vai atrapalhar os que já foram corrigidos (manualmente), por isto na minha resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/279926/3635 eu usei um grupo com uma negação que contém a virgula `([^,])`, assim evita do replace ser aplicado em strings que já estão com `,ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8"` ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> e no campo <kbd>Find what</kbd> adicione isto:

```
htmlspecialchars\(([^,]+?)\)
```

E no campo <kbd>Replace with</kbd> isto:

```
htmlspecialchars\($1, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8"\)
```

Veja o exemplo no notepad++:

> [image: notepad++ com replace em regex]

---

### Explicando a *regex*:

- O `\(` e o `\)` é para escapar os parenteses que em regex são usados para grupos, desta forma não serão usados assim, serão como aspas normais.
- O `([^,]+?)` forma um grupo que procura tudo que não tiver virgula, assim vai evitar de fazer a substituição em locais aonde a string já estiver correta (`htmlspecialchars($str,ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8")`)
- o `$1` no campo <kbd>Replace with</kbd> (`htmlspecialchars\($1, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8"\)`) serve para pegar o valor do grupo `([^,]+?)` no momento do replace.

Comment: Adoro mini TL;DRs =] e ainda mais com gifs

Comment: @danieltakeshi Grato :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, funcionou demais garoto. Muito obrigado mesmo... eu não tenho essa competência com regex.... abs e sucesso.